# Getting firefox to remember password again

Tags: windows-7, firefox

A while back I entered a password into a website - firefox then asked me if I wanted it to remember the passord for me. I selected the option to never offer to remember passords for this saite again... Now I have changed my mind - I'd love firefox to remember my password for this site, but I have no idea how to undo my previous selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. At the top of the Firefox window, on the menu bar, click on the Tools and select Options.
2. Select the Security panel.
3. If it isn't already check marked, check Remember passwords for sites.
4. To the right of **Remember passwords for sites**, click the Exceptions button.
5. Make sure that the site you're trying to log in to isn't in the list.
         * If it is, select the entry and click Remove.
6. Click Close.
7. Click OK to close the Options window.

Now that you've configured Firefox to remember passwords, try logging in to the site again.

[Source](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/username+and+password+not+remembered)

Comment: Hey, I just put up the same thing

Comment: But you got the credit.

Comment: You were late. You gotta be faster ;)

Comment: Clear case of the fastest gun in the West! Guess you need some more practicing on your shooting speed @Pajarito

Comment: No, honest to god, mine was up 2 minutes earlier

Comment: @Pajarito: Hover on the answer times and you'll see the exact times of the answers. Mine: 13:58:09Z; yours: 14:05:21Z. Which one do you think is earlier? :)

Comment: Really? My loaded with my answer and still didn't show yours. Oh, well.

Comment: Please stop whining. If you want to get the votes, you gotta be fast here (Wild West Rules). If you lack of speed, then don't complain. Go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com to learn more about the mechanism of SOFU sites.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't trying to whine or be sarcastic with that last comment.

Comment: OK, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to : *Tools > Options > Security*

Under passwords section:

Make sure "Remember passwords for websites is checked", then click the exceptions button and delete your site from that list.

**Note:** For Ubuntu and some other types of linux, *Tools > Options* **is** *Edit > Preferences*